# 'File' class not found in submitForm(...) - uploading managed_file

Tags: forms, 8, files

I have an image field in my custom module's form:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

use Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\SafeMarkup;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;

class MyModuleForm extends FormBase {

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['image_file'] = array(
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#name' => 'image_file',
      '#title' => t('Block image'),
      '#size' => 40,
      '#description' => t("Image should be less than 400 pixels wide and in JPG format."),
      '#upload_location' => 'public://myimages/'
    ); 
...
```

And for `submitForm(...)` I use:

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    $image = $form_state->getValue('image_file');
    $file = File::load( $image[0] );
    $file->setPermanent();
    $file->save();
    ...
```

But when I use the form to submit image I get error (in log):

> Error: Class 'Drupal\my_module\Form\File' not found in ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add it in a use statement in your class (at the top of the file with the rest of the use statements)

```
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
```